# Datetime utc issue after migrating to .NET Core 7

Tags: .net, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I migrated a  .NET Core 3 application to .NET 7. All the date fields were in `DateTime` data type. Since the migration the date is returning without the "Z" specifier that indicates it is an UTC Datetime.

What is the reason for this? I can put a fix by changing all the date data types `DateTimeOffSet`. I am not pretty sure why this is changed after the .NET migration.

```
public class Shipment : IAudit
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

//Automapper

```
public class ShipmentProfile : Profile
{
    public ShipmentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Shipment, ShipmentDto>();
        CreateMap<ShipmentDto, Shipment>();
    }
}
```

//Db call

```
public IQueryable<Shipment> GetShipments()
{
    return db.Shipments.ProjectTo<Shipment>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}
```

response from the old endpoint,
{ updated: "2023-01-16T07:47:50.4462437Z" }

response from the new endpoint,
{ updated: "2023-01-16T07:47:50.4462437" }

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Note that DateTime and DateTimeOffset themselves aren't string representations - "the date" doesn't have a Z specifier or not. Only a *string representation* does, which means it's important how you *obtain* that string representation. That's why it's useful to see some code...

Comment: @JonSkeet added the code. Sorry for the late reply. I was away.

Comment: @Joshua OK; and what's the bit that shows the presence or absence of the Z? is the real problem here the choice/configuration of JSON serializer? have you checked the `.Kind` of the value when fetched on both platforms to see if the `.Kind` is the same?

Comment: @MarcGravell What you mean by .Kind? it is the response in postman that shows the absence.

Comment: @Joshua DateTime has a .Kind property; the first thing you should do is check whether this matches between the two runtimes - if it doesn't, the problem may be in the *data access* code - if it is Unkown, you may be able to use DateTime.SpecifyKind(...) to mark it as Utc; however, I suspect that the problem is the JSON encode.

Comment: @MarcGravell gotcha. I am changing the kind globally to see if it works.

Comment: @MarcGravell fixed. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding the following code to startup,

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).